# Mac OS Server 3.1.1 authentication issue

Tags: macos

After upgrading to Mac Server 3.1.1, I got the following issue whenever I do something to the user management part.

> Existing connection is not authenticated, password change denied.

I found a KB on Apple website about this issue and followed all instructions, no luck. Has anyone known and fixed this issue yet?

[OS X Server (Mavericks): After upgrading or migrating, network user cannot be created](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5289)

Answer (score 2):

Well, eventually I fixed this issue. By the hint from the following article, I just simply destroyed the existing OD and build a new OD. I know this is not a good practice nor a good solution, but it did fix my issue.

For those have a lot users in their Mac Servers, maybe you should archive the OD and import it again after a new OD was built.

[I found the following article that gave a detail workaround](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23839382#23839382)